# Rails Engine AESCRYPT gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-engines

I developed a rails engine app(mountable engine). In engine gemspec file i added `s.add_dependency "aescrypt"`
then i gave `bundle install` after that in rails console i followed the steps from this https://github.com/Gurpartap/aescrypt" > link  but it shows error

```
NameError: uninitialized constant AESCrypt\
from (irb):4
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:69:in `console'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:8:in `require'
    from bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put `require "aescrypt"` in engine.rb